# Calculate the minimum distance for each control unit from the treated unit

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, r-sp

The dataset contains the treated and control villages. We have the exact latitude and longitude of each village (see df_input).

I need to calculate the distance of the closest treated village for all the control villages.  Also, create a variable called "distance" which reports the distance to the closest treated village for that particular control village (see df_output, the numbers are made up).

```
df_input <- data.frame( village= c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), outcome = c(1000,1500,1500,2000,1700,1700), 
                        status = c("Treated","Treated","Control","Control","Control","Control"), 
                        latitude = c(22.54394, 28.54394, 21.54394, 8.54394, 29.54394, 35.54394),
                        longtiude= c(75.15433, 85.15433, 74.15433, 65.15433, 86.15433, 95.15433))    

df_output <- data.frame( village= c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), outcome = c(1000,1500,1500,2000,1700,1700), 
                         status = c("Treated","Treated","Control","Control","Control","Control"),
                         latitude = c(22.54394, 28.54394, 21.54394, 8.54394, 29.54394, 35.54394),
                         longtiude= c(75.15433, 85.15433, 74.15433, 65.15433, 86.15433, 95.15433),
                         distance = I(list(NULL,NULL,1,10,2,20)))
```

I am new to spatial analysis, is it doable in R? If yes, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is. look into the geodistance function

Comment: It seems that McSpatial package is no longer compatible with the latest version of R.

Comment: you could use `distGeo` function